# Prepend (instead of append) virtualenv path to login shell $PATH

Tags: python, macos, shell, virtualenv, zsh

Why does my virtualenv path get appended to the $PATH variable of a login shell? Is it possible to have it prepended so it gets searched first?

```
Last login: Tue Aug 26 18:35:15 on ttys000
➜  ~  . ./venvs/py_venv/bin/activate
(py_venv)➜  ~  echo $PATH
/Users/aj/venvs/py_venv/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin
(py_venv)➜  ~  zsh -l -c 'echo $PATH'
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/aj/venvs/py_venv/bin
(py_venv)➜  ~
```

Here is my .zshrc file: https://gist.github.com/ajw0100/b10672e065977793ac79

Comment: What are you doing prior to the `echo $PATH`? Just opening the shell? Sourcing **activate** within the *virtualenv*? I use *zsh* as well, and was not able to reproduce this behavior, even when changing my .zshrc around to add some of the plugins, etc. If you use the stock *oh-my-zsh* .zshrc, do you still get the append behavior?

Comment: Just opening the shell and sourcing activate. I've updated the question to make this more clear. I'm using stock oh-my-zsh. I can switch in the stock .zshrc file and let you know.

Comment: Hmm... I don't see that even if I invoke it the same way you are (I usually `source` it) -- the venv is always prepended. I'm on *Ubuntu*, whereas I see this is tagged *osx*, so while I wouldn't think that would really matter here, perhaps there is a quirk stemming from there... From what I gather, it's meant to be `source`ed. Does that change anything if you do it that way?

Comment: Was something in my config. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: Sure, no problem. Interesting that a reinstall fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. Was something in my config. I uninstalled oh-my-zsh ran `rm -rf .zsh*` and re-installed oh-my-zsh and now it works:

```
Last login: Tue Aug 26 19:01:26 on ttys000
➜  ~  echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin
➜  ~  . ./venvs/py_venv/bin/activate
(py_venv)➜  ~  echo $PATH
/Users/aj/venvs/py_venv/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin
(py_venv)➜  ~  zsh -l -c "echo $PATH"
/Users/aj/venvs/py_venv/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin
(py_venv)➜  ~
```